# Vuetify performance issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have picked vuetify for an offline PWA project where I work with indexed DB and some notable size data (5k-6k/collection). I have to transfer it between vuex and IDB after I get them from the server.
Reading and saving them is kinda slow (200-300 ms), and freezing the UI for a short time. I thought making a full-screen loading screen while it was loading helped, but it still make the loader stutter.
Also, I have some problems when I am navigating between pages. Loading v-lists (with infinity loading) and swiper (swiper slider) freeze the UI and it feels a little bit off. Especially, when I am adding vibrating to the buttons. The freezing delays the vibration for 100-200 ms and I don't know I am touched the button or not.

**Things I've tried so far:**

- Looping through the list elements, and freezing the objects at vuex mutations (I want to keep the reactivity for array methods). It feels faster, however cloning arrays can delay the initial loading. And still not satisfying.
- Using requestAnimationFrame solves the freezing at navigation, but delays the rendering of childcomponents. Also doesn't seem like the best solution.
- Using less dom elements. I'am using infinity scrolls for v-lists. It still loads slow despite it only rendering 15 rows. I cannot use a virtual list, because the list elements have different heights. I didn't find a carousel/swiper with
  proper virtualization. Vue-awesome-swiper is the most popular, but it loads incredibly slow.

**My app**

Sadly I cannot share the project here, But I don't use any extraordinary code, that's why I am confused about the low performance.

At service workflow

Getting data as JSON from the server -> vuex action -> committing mutation and saving data to IDB with Dexie's bulkPut -> mutation freezes the objects and saves to the state

At visualization

components using mapgetters to get the lists from vuex. Using these getters, I am making computed properties to filter/reorder data (these methods run under 30ms, so they shouldn't make issues).

I couldn't find any helpful information on how to make my application faster. Even scrolling down the list seems slowy/laggy. I could use webworker to handle IDB at initial loading, but the UI animations would still be slow. Should I use less v-container/v-layout/v-flex etc... and adding native elements to my app? Currently, I am using only vuetify elements.

As I am loading all my data at starting, I am expecting a slower initial loading time for sure, but smooth navigating and fast loading after that.

Comment: We are talking about 0.1 and 0.3 seconds, it takes 0.3 seconds for our eye to blink so... You sure about those times? That sounds quite fast for saving data. Ideal if you ask me.

Comment: Yes, as data processing time, it is fast. But it makes the UI unresponsive/slow. As 2019, I don't want to see stuttering animations and additional loaders once my app is loaded.

Comment: I've struggled with vuetify's animation performance for nearly 2 years now. It's gotten a lot better, but it's still extremely noticable in some areas like you mention sadly.

Comment: Without any code it's really hard to provide help here. I understand that you cannot share the full project, but that's not needed: you should create a minimal example which still exposes the problem (and it's not unlikely that you will find the issue while creating that example).

If you don't want to do that: my preferred way to deal with such issues is to mock out single subsystems and see their impact on performance. E.g. replace all store/db lookup with static data. If the UI is still equally laggy, you know that it's not the data layer.

Comment: I tried so hard to fix it, than o found materialize and next, then I switched to sveltejs. Now working on UI with styles of my own

Comment: The topic is very broad. The animated loader can be built using css/svg or canvas and webworker. Related the overall vue performance I would suggest to start with [1](https://teamhood.com/engineering/vue-performance-tips/), [2](https://teamhood.com/engineering/vue-js-component-props/), [3](https://teamhood.com/engineering/better-vue-performance-with-selective-object-reuse/).

Answer (score 0):

My site is entirely on Laravel and Vuetify technology. Just a few recommendations. First, there must be a very fast server. Not average in terms of speed, but a fast one. Secondly, the page should not have full-page Vue components. They are first mounted, then displayed. The user sees this as a display after some delay. Further, there should be no data loading via the API after the layout is displayed (the getData method in the mounted hook). And, of course, loading a large amount of data via prop {{json_encode($data)}} delays and degrades performance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30839182)

Answer (score 0):

We've built an application with vue/vuetify, where the main component is a complex multidimensional grid  generated on the fly.

Our first iteration was painfully slow, once, with meaningful data, we got a rendering time of 9 sec ...

The solution to our problem was two fold:

- use [functional components](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#functional-components) wherever possible,
- use `Object.freeze` on data that doesn't need to be reactive (as mentioned) - [at this link](https://codeburst.io/5-vue-performance-tips-98e184338439) an explanation of the optimization technique

Now rendering the same component takes fractions of a second.

From the doc:

> Functional components are an alternative form of component that don't
> have any state of their own. They act like pure functions: props in,
> vnodes out. They are rendered without creating a component instance
> (i.e. no this), and without the usual component lifecycle hooks.

as always, just my 2c :)